# I have created a simple node server with CORS enabled. But when I do node server.js, it's throwing error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, node-modules

```
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();



app.use(cors());

app.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port${port}`));
```

I have created a simple node server with CORS enabled. But when I do, node server.js, it throws a particular error, which I'm not able to figure it out.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Cnetric\Desktop\reactonline\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

Can someone please help me on this. I'm not able to troubleshoot. I'm new to node and not able to figure it out.

My folder structure

reactonline-> src, public, node_modules, package.

Then under the src folder, all my files are there.

[image]

Comment: What is the name of  your starting point file name? Do you have server.js file exist in your reactonline folder?

Comment: @SvetoslavPetrov yes I have a attached a screenshot of it......

Comment: @Think-Twice yes I have included the folder structure in the post, which I have edited now.

Comment: Your server.js is in src folder and your package.json is in reactonline folder so how does it work. You need to move server.js file to the root folder i.e., reactonline

Comment: @Think-Twice thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments. Your package.json file is in root folder and you have server.js in src folder which is the problem.

Move your server.js file under your root folder i.e., reactonline and resolve path issues if you have included any files in server.js. It will work now

Regarding getting data from external source you need to use node-rest-client library. [Check here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) for more details about the library

First install it

```
npm install -s node-rest-client
```

then here

```
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;//import it here
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

   var client = new Client();

   // direct way
   client.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", (data, response) => {
    res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express', data: data });
   });
});

const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port${port}`));
```

Comment: yeah it's working now....But I'm not able to fetch the data....from the url

Comment: To talk to any external URL's to get the data you need to use node-rest-client library

Comment: How will I configure it in my current server. Could you give me an insight on this.

Comment: Updated my answer check

Answer (score 2):

It tries to find the file in the wrong location:

```
'C:\Users\Cnetric\Desktop\reactonline\server.js'
```

It's actually in:

```
'C:\Users\Cnetric\Desktop\reactonline\src\server.js'
```

You should run the node command in the correct folder.